# Bash for loop on remote server

Tags: bash, for-loop, ssh, grep, remote-server

I am new to bash and I am trying to create a script that checks for malicious files. Specifically those using global PHP variables to hide content. Below is an example line of such file:

```
$GLOBALS['qahtm46']($zadoh31) < 12) { $GLOBALS['wlcrh95']($i34, $gxfej87);
```

I need to check and get the results remotely, here is how I currently connect and fetch other information:

```
eval=$(ssh -q -t -o GSSAPIAuthentication=yes user@$webs "/usr/bin/ssuu $domain" << EOF
grep -l -r --include=*.php -PHn "(eval\(.*\);)" .
exit
EOF
)
```

When I `echo $eval` it prints the filename of any matches. Great!

Whenever I run the below command on the server directly:

```
for x in $(find public_html -type f -name '*.php' | xargs grep -ol 'GLOBALS'); do grep -o 'GLOBALS' $x | wc -l | tr '\n' ' ' ; echo $x; printf "\n"; sleep 1; done
exit
EOF
)
```

I get the correct Output:

```
1 public_html/update.php
363 public_html/sites/all/themes/corporate_blue/images/proxy2.php
363 public_html/sites/all/themes/corporate_blue/images/proxy.php
2 public_html/sites/all/modules/views/views.api.php
2 public_html/sites/all/modules/imce/tpl/imce-page.tpl.php
1 public_html/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/includes/filemanager.config.php
4 public_html/modules/simpletest/drupal_web_test_case.php
```

However when I run this using my usual method I do not get any output, if I output to a file, the file is created but nothing is written to it:

```
globals=$(ssh -q -t -o GSSAPIAuthentication=yes user@$webs "/usr/bin/ssuu $domain" << EOF
for x in $(find public_html -type f -name '*.php' | xargs grep -ol 'GLOBALS'); do grep -o 'GLOBALS' $x | wc -l | tr '\n' ' ' ; echo $x; printf "\n"; sleep 1; done
exit
EOF
)
```

Can anybody see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this:

```
ssh server << EOF
for x in $(find ...); ...
EOF
```

The content of the here-document gets evaluated by the local shell before passing the script to the server.
To have it evaluated on the server, double-quote the opening `EOF`:

```
ssh server << "EOF"
for x in $(find ...); ...
EOF
```